# HAProxy + OpenVPN retain real IP of client

Tags: openvpn, haproxy, static-ip

**Setup**

HAProxy tcp mode
with OpenVPN servers as backend, all on the same machine

**Problem**

OpenVPN shows localhost IP instead of real IP of client in status

**Question**

- Is there any method to retain the real IP of the connected client?
- If not, is there any way to at least log the real IP in HAProxy? Or control it via a hook?

Comment: Why use TCP proxy at all? OpenVPN will be slower in TCP mode than UDP - more round trips, because you encapsulate TCP in TCP.
As for logging, yes, haproxy can log real IP of clients. `mode tcp` and `option tcplog` will help you start.

Comment: My use case forces me to use TCP with the devices I'm connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the real IP on your OpenVPN Server you should take a look to haproxy's transparent proxy mode. You need to route also the return traffic through your haproxy.

As already mentioned, you can log the connections with tcplog.

And I also would recommend to use OpenVPN with UDP .